# Embedded .doc and .txt viewer in React js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I have a react application where users can drag and drop there files on the left side and after uploading the file, when you click on it, you see the contents of the file. I have rendered image and files with pdf extensions into the application. I am confused how to render .doc and .text files into the web apk built in React.

Does anyone know how to render .doc and .txt files in react app ?

Comment: Please show us, what you already tried. What did work out for you, what didnt? What exactly is the question here? What are you confused about?

Comment: I want to render .doc and .txt files using React.

Answer (score 7):

Here is one approach to display docx page inside your react-app (via Google Docs Viewer)

**doc.js**

```
import React from "react";

const DocIframe = ({ source }) => {
  if (!source) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>;
  }

  const src = source;
  return (
    <div>
      <iframe
        src={"https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=" + src + "&embedded=true"}
        title="file"
        width="100%"
        height="600"
      ></iframe>
    </div>
  );
};

export default DocIframe;
```

And inside your main component:

```
import React from "react";
import DocViewer from "./doc.js";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Sample Doc file:</h1>
      <DocViewer source="https://file-examples-com.github.io/uploads/2017/02/file-sample_100kB.doc" />
    </div>
  );
}
```

To see a sample working app: [see this codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/sample-doc-in-react-hlct4)

Comment: Does the iframe with google docs viewer requires Google authentication ? and is their any kind of daily limit for rendering the files ?

Comment: It doesn't require authentication as you can see from the example sandbox. And there's no daily quota that I'm aware of (and is quite unlikely since it on their public/free service)

Comment: In my web the user uploads the file from the local computer into the web and before submitting the files when the user clicks on the file it should get previewed. 

<iframe  src={"https://docs.google.com/gview?url=" + this.state.file + "&embedded=true"}  id="frame-id" allowFullScreen={true}/>

I implemented this but now when user clicks on the file, the preview is blank and the file is forced to download. Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use **embed** tag if the **iframe** is not working properly.

```
<embed type="application/pdf" src={'https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=' + src +'&embedded=true'} />
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).